# Load CSV file in Django view and turn into HTML table

Tags: python, django

I have this view code

```
def datatable(request, file):
    csv_fp = open(f'data/{file}.csv', 'r')
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_fp)
    headers = [col for col in reader.fieldnames]
    out = [row for row in reader]
    return render(request, 'datatable.html', {'data' : out, 'headers' : headers})
```

and here's my template

```
<table id="table" class="display" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for header in headers%}
      <th>{{ header }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      {% for row in out%}
      <td>{{row}}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm trying to turn this CSV into a table in my Django template. The headers are done correctly, but the rows are off. Is there a better way to read the rows so it'll go into tbody easier?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that your problem is {% for row in out %}, you are passing {'data' : out}

Try:

```
<table id="table" class="display" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for header in headers %}
      <th>{{ header }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      {% for row in data %}
      <td>{{ row }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The error you point to was indeed a problem but your code does not correct the second problem that you also need to iterate on each row to display its cells (see answer by Aditya Gupta).

Answer (score 1):

row will contain a list of all rows as dict so we need to lterate through dict values using another for loop.

```
<table id="table" class="display" style="width: 100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for header in headers %}
      <th>{{ header }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   {% for row in data %}
    <tr>
      {% for val in row.values %}
      <td>{{ val }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
   {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: row will contain a list of all rows as dict so we need to lterate through dict values using another for loop.